# calculate total of a struct property using reduce method

Tags: swift3

I want to calculate total scores in a student lis but I get this error. What is wrong with my reduce method implementation?

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_, _) -> Int' to expected argument type '(Result, Student) -> Result'
```

here is the code:

```
import UIKit

struct Student {
    let name: String
    var score: Int
}

var studentsList: [Student]

let totalScore = studentsList.reduce(0) {$0.score + $1.score}
```

Comment: `$0` is the accumulator, it's `Int`, and doesn't have a `score`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
let totalScore = studentsList.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.score }
```

Not

```
let totalScore = studentsList.reduce(0) { $0.score + $1.score }
```

Here `(0)` is initial result `$0` is `Result` in your case it is `Int` and `$1` is `Student` type.

Answer (score 0):

first studentsList initialized

```
var studentsList: [Student] = [] //or some list
```

and it should

```
let totalScore = studentsList.reduce(0) {$0.0 + $0.1.score}
```

instead

```
let totalScore = studentsList.reduce(0) {$0.score + $1.score}
```